# "Freundschaftlich" vs. "freundlich"

Tags: difference, adjective, meaning

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den zwei Wörtern? "Freundschaftlich" erscheint mir absurd.

Comment: Insbesondere impliziert Ersteres Letzteres nicht, manchmal muß man mit einem Freunde ein ernstes Wort sprechen, ohne direkt freundlich zu sein. Weiterhin sind unter Freunden Umgangsformen erlaubt, die nicht unter den Begriff "freundlich" fallen.

Comment: Inwiefern absurd? "Freundschaftlich" findest du in allen gängigen Dictionaries. Hast du einen bestimmten Kontext, auf den du dich beziehst?

Answer (score 9):

**Freundschaftlich** bezieht sich auf eine Freundschaft,- verstanden als Steigerung einer Kameradschaft, welche wiederum die Steigerung einer Bekanntschaft ist.

> Sie pflegen einen freundschaftlichen Umgang miteinander.

Man spricht beispielsweise von freundschaftlichem Umgang miteinander, wenn zwei Menschen zumindest vermeintlich die Vertrautheit einer Freundschaft in ihrer Interaktion voraussetzen.

> They are friendly with each other. / They treat each other like (close) friends.

Das Wort wird tatsächlich so genutzt.

Interessant ist hier vor allem, dass im Deutschen viel stärker zwischen Freunden und Bekannten unterschieden wird, als es im englischen Sprachgebrauch für "friends" und "acquaintances" üblich ist.

---

**Freundlich** hat wiederum eine viel schwächere Bedeutung und bedeutet, dass man über die gesellschaftlichen Mindeststandards in der Interaktion zwischen zwei Menschen hinausgeht.

> Er reagiert freundlich auf ihre Bitte. Er ist eine freundliche Person.

Bereits ein Lächeln oder eine wohlwollende Reaktion qualifizieren als freundlich.

> He reacts kindly to her request. He is a friendly person.

Comment: "friendly" als Übersetzung für "Freundlich", wenn man es von "Freundschaftlich" abgrenzen möchte ist meiner Meinung nach ungeschickt. Zwar kann es so übersetzt werden, dabei ist jedoch mehr die "freundschaftliche Freundlichkeit" anstatt die "höfliche / generelle Freundlichkeit" gemeint.

Comment: Genau, das ist mir beim Lesen Deines Beitrags auch gleich aufgefallen.   Vielleicht sollte man die häufigere Verwendung (subjektiv, mein Hintergrund: GB) im Sinne von "he's a friendly lad" abtrennen von der Verwendung als "they are friendly with each other". Danke für den Hinweis.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

Freundlich = kind / nice

> Your Father was very kind to me = Dein Vater war sehr freundlich zu
>   mir.

Freundschaftlich = amicable / friendly

> Wir haben eine freundschaftliche Beziehung = We have a friendly
>   relationship.

Comment: Lustigerweise, erwähnst du in der anderen Antwort, dass "friendly" eine 'ungeschickte' Übersetzung ist, und verwendest sie doch selber. Auch "amicable" ist unglücklich, da sie auch im Sinne von "freundlich" verwendet werden kann. "amicable manner" beispielsweise. Ich befürchte, eine Ein-Wort-Übersetzung für "freundschaftlich" gibt es nicht, welche nicht gleichzeitig "freundlich" abdeckt. Hier muss daher eine Definition herhalten, z.b. ausm OALD: 3 "treating somebody as a friend" und/oder 4 "not treating somebody/something as an enemy"

Answer (score 2):

*Freundschaftlich* ist auch nicht immer gleichzusetzen mit *freundlich*! Ich kann zu jemandem, mit dem ich *freundschaftlichen Umgang* habe, auch durchaus mal neutral oder unfreundlich sein.

Gleichzeitig bedeutet *freundschaftlicher Umgang* nicht unbedingt, dass ich mit jemandem tatsächlich befreundet bin - ich verhalte mich ihmgegenüber nur so, als wären wir es.